# Why doesn't file_get_contents load phpscript properly in this example?

Tags: php, javascript

I wrote a bit of code, that in essence does the following:

```
<div id="thisDiv">
</div>

<?php
echo "<script>document.getElementById('thisDiv').innerHTML = '".addslashes(str_replace(array("\n", "\r"), "", file_get_contents('/path/to/file/example.php'')))."';</script>";
?>
```

However, I noticed that this doesn't work: nothing enclosed in  `<?php ?>` tags inside example.php makes their way to the div. Why is this and is their a way around it?

Comment: Could you show the generated HTML file? Are there errors in the JavaScript console?

Comment: There are no errors. The HTMLpage shows up normally, except for everything within the php tags which seems to be removed.

Comment: when you use file_get_contents(), it doesn't run any PHP code that is in the file you're trying to get contents from.

Comment: You need to show the generated HTML. What you have shown works ok. http://jsfiddle.net/ut6G8/

Comment: @kennypu Thanks, that would explain it. Is there some function that does allow this, without having to go through a complicated ajax route?

Comment: i'll post it as an answer

Comment: @EdwardStumperd And if you look in the JavaScript error console you see "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined" a couple of lines before the one you've shown in the question. I thought you said there are no errors in the console?

Comment: @Juhana Where do you see this in firebug? I'm not getting any errors here..

Comment: Nevermind, seems like the error isn't there anymore. (It was line 49 of choose_dimension.js)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when using `file_get_contents()`, if you try to use it on a PHP script, any PHP within the file will not execute. If you want to return a PHP file as a string, one method is to use the `ob_*()` functions:

```
ob_start();
include '/path/to/file/example.php';
$content = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
```

now you can use `$content` which will be example.php with PHP executed as as string.

Comment: Thank you! This is in fact a very good solution to my problem.